# create a windows 2000 batch file that executes a mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

I want to create a batch file that I can run from the desktop. This batch file should execute a stored procedure in MySQL.

This is what I have so far:

```
cd\
cd Program Files
cd mysql
cd mysql server 5.1
cd bin
mysql.exe -h host_ip -u login --password=password
mysql use database_name \g
mysql call sp_stored_proc_name \g
```

The batch file logs into the server but it doesn't execute the stored procedure.

Comment: When running "mysql.exe -h host_ip -u login --password=password mysql use database_name \g mysql call sp_stored_proc_name \g" manually. Does it work? I.e. when going into the BIN folder via cmd and runnniing the mysql.exe command - does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Put your SQL commands to call the stored procedure as if you were at the command line

```
call sp_stored_proc;
```

in a .sql file (i.e. stored_proc.sql), then put the following in your batch file.

```
cd "\Program Files\mysql server 5.1\bin" 
mysql -h host -ulogin -ppassword -Ddatabase_name < \path\to\stored_proc.sql > output.txt
```